# Include guards in C++

Tags: c++, include, include-guards

I use include guards quite a lot, but I've recently found a strange use of them which I cannot understand.

```
#ifndef B1SteppingAction_h
#define B1SteppingAction_h 1

// rest of my code

#endif
```

What's that "1" in the define guard? I haven't found this anywhere else.
Thank you!

Comment: It's just defining the macro to have a value 1 instead of merely defining the macro with no value.  If the macro isn't used elsewhere then it doesn't matter much whether or not it has a value, it only matters whether or not it's defined.

Comment: Its *pointless* if that macro is only being used as an include guard. If it is being used as a value expansion somewhere, then it's meaningful.

Comment: It defines the macro with a particular value, which means that it's being used as something other than a simple include guard. Or it means that whoever wrote it is trying too hard.

Comment: I suppose it might be used to tell between different versions of the same file (and see which one was actually included) using the macro value.

Comment: @Catsunami (a sudden fit of pedantry, ignore it) "to tell between different versions of the same *declarations, possibly included from a different file*"

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi, makes sense! I was actually thinking of a situation where main.c (or whatever) includes "processor.h", and that processor.h contains definitions specific to some hardware. But the hardware might change and the main needs to know which processor was selected? I've never used it like that, but I could imagine it might be.